# PHP(Codeigniter) SOAP Client

Tags: php, codeigniter, soap

Im new to SOAP the code below gives me a blank page. I want those data under DetailQuote. Like id, companyName, etc. And also is my code has a problem or the .wsdl itself? Thanks!

```
$companyId = id here;
$secureKey = key here;

$client = new SoapClient('http://www.tadawul.com.sa/Tadawul_WebAPI/services/GetDetailQuote/wsdl/GetDetailQuote.wsdl');


$session = $client->getDetailQuoteForCompany($companyId, $secureKey);
var_dump($client->__getFunctions()); 
$filters = array('id', 'companyName', 'open');

$response = $client->DetailQuote($session, $filters);
echo $response;
```

Comment: use nusoap libray it is easy to use and handle

Comment: how about the php soap client?